# OneDrive get access token request case-sensitivity

Tags: c#, onedrive

I have a WinForms C# app using the OneDrive API. All was working up until last week when new token requests after authorizing the user started failing telling me that the 'code' parameter was invalid.

After reviewing my code, I noticed that routine that was extracting the authorization code from the authorize call back was using `.ToLowerInvariant` which resulted in the authorization code starting with a lower-case 'm'. When I removed the `.ToLowerInvariant`, the code started with an upper-case 'M' and the token request worked correctly.

Obviously I'm happy that my code is now working, but I'd like to try and understand why it suddenly started having problems.

Many thanks

James